# use variable as dict key in clojure

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have such code

```
(def person {:name "Steve" :age 24 :salary 7886 :company "Acme"})
(def nm 'name)
(println (person :nm))
```

and I want to use `nm` variable as a key to `person` dictionary like I tried in last line. Is it possible in clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought it is more idiomatic to use the key like a function
(when defining the dict `person` in the background all keys are defined as accessor functions for objects of this "type"/dict):

```
(:name person) ;; => "Steve"

;; or:
(def nm :name)
(nm person) ;; => "Steve"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but the map uses a keyword `:name`, not a symbol `'name`, so you need to change your code to be

```
(def nm :name)
(println (person nm))
```

or (clearer IMHO):

```
(println (get person nm))
```

with results

```
(person nm)     => "Steve"
(get person nm) => "Steve"
```

Please also see [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), esp. the Clojure CheatSheet.

Answer (score 3):

There is some confusion with keywords and symbols here.

```
(type 'name)
clojure.lang.Symbol
(type :nm)
clojure.lang.Keyword
```

So your keys in `person` are keywords.  Your def `nm` is to a symbol.  And
your call into person uses again a keyword.

So you are most likely best off using keywords here.  E.g.

```
(def nm :name)
#'user/nm
(println (person nm))
Steve
```